# Increasing Appengine Instances through API?

Tags: google-app-engine

We have a case that when we send push notifications to our app users, load on appengine increases. It is found that appengine takes 2 minutes to handle the flood of requests with reduced latency. By then user is already out of app as the server is not responding when he makes an action.

I was looking for an API for appengine through which we can instruct it to increase instances for next 5 minutes. Since I know load is going to come beforehand I can reduce the latency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [App Engine Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/) for this and, if your app is in automatic scaling, use the [apps.services.versions.patch](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions/patch) method to increase the number of idle instances for your service. You can't specify a time period for the change to apply though. You'll need to schedule the required API calls.

Comment: Thank you LundinCast. It solved my problem. I used API Explorer to test it.